# Check if text exists on a webpage using Python + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium to see if a certain string exists on a webpage and return true/false accordingly. I can't seem to find anyone else who's used this to return a boolean.

I've included my code for the function below, although I've also tried a bunch of other variations including webdriverwait, body text search, search for element by xpath, unittest and assert, and more. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
def findtext(wordsearch):
    # find out if specific text is on the webpage and print result
    if wordsearch in driver.page_source:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: That should work.  There must be some other problem.  Please post your whole code.

Comment: Try `print(driver.page_source)` and see what's the content of the page. Sometimes the website will block scrapping.

Comment: Just updated - edit includes entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It just has to do with the case sensitivity in python so I wrote another function to adapt to all uppercase, all lowercase, and first-letter uppercase.